# How to change object string value in to number

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object like below. Sometimes it will contain `status` sometimes not. I want to convert status value format into `Number` when it in object.

```
var obj={ 
  name: 'abc',
  status: '1',
  updated_time: { 
    '$gt': 2019-11-03T00:00:00.000Z,
    '$lt': 2019-11-03T15:23:55.838Z 
  } 
}
```

i've tried as below but it's not converted;

```
if(obj.status){
  parseInt(obj.status)
}
console.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$",obj)
```

*console.log print*

> $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$${ 
>         name: 'abc',
>         status: '1',
>         updated_time:
>          { '$gt': 2019-11-03T00:00:00.000Z,
>            '$lt': 2019-11-03T15:23:55.838Z } 
>       }

Comment: `parseInt` returns the converted value. You are not storing it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign back parsed value to `object.status`. parseInt method just evaluate the value it doesn't changes value by itself in object. you need to change value manually on object.

```js
var obj = {
  name: 'abc',
  status: '1',
  updated_time: {
    '$gt': '2019-11-03T00:00:00.000Z',
    '$lt': '2019-11-03T15:23:55.838Z'
  }
}

if (obj.status) {
  obj.status = parseInt(obj.status)
}
console.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$", obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` returns a value and you need to assign this value to `object.status` property:

```
if(obj.status){
  obj.status = parseInt(obj.status)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a simple mistake mate. You haven't assigned the value.

You can do that by :

```
if(obj.status){
  obj.status = parseInt(obj.status); //obj.status is being reassigned
}
```

Hope it helps :)